# Errors while posting form data using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is going to be a little long.

I have a form, from which data needs to go to a url. Also 3 parameters need to be present - action = create (which means that the data is going to be added and not updated or deleted, type = school(which means it should go to the school table), and school is going to be the JSON object which contains the form data.

So here is my form

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Look I'm AJAXing!</title>

<!-- load jquery via CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<sccript src="magic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <h1>Form</h1>

    <!-- OUR FORM -->
    <form method="POST" enctype="application/json">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="school">
    <input type="hidden" name="school" value="response">

    <!-- NAME -->
    <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
        <!-- errors will go here -->
    </div><br>

    <div id="address-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address">
        <!-- errors will go here -->
    </div><br>

    <div id="website-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="website">Website</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="website">
        <!-- errors will go here -->
    </div><br>

    <div id="twitter-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="twitter">Twitter</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="twitter">
    </div><br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>

</form>

</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

The following is my .js file

```
// magic.js
$(document).ready(function() {

// process the form
$('form').submit(function(event) {

    // get the form data
    var school = {
        'action' : $('input[name=action]').val(),
        'type' : $('input[name=type]').val(),
        'school': $('input[name=school]').val(),
        'Name'              : $('input[name=Name]').val(),
        'address'             : $('input[name=address]').val(),
        'website'    : $('input[name=website]').val(),
        'twitter'    : $('input[name=twitter]').val()
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        contentType : 'json',
        beforeSend  : function(request){
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        },
        url         : 'https://your_url.aspx', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : school, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    encode          : true,
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
    })

     // using the done promise callback
    .done(function(data) {

       // log data to the console so we can see
        console.log(data); 

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
    });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

Despite scouring the internet to find a lot of solutions, I have been getting a lot of errors for Access-Control-Allow origin, etc. I am now getting to see the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://your_url.aspx. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Any idea where am I going wrong?

If all is right, my console should show like :
Object{ status: "ok" , response : "id: the_recent_added_number" }

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: A question, why is this question tagged with PHP? There's no PHP here and you even post the data to an "aspx"-page?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this isn't really a duplicate even though it may seem like, because I have seen the solutions there like making crossDomain: true etc but of no help.

Comment: You should read the links in the accepted answer. It's the page you're posting _to_ that must have Allow-Origin-headers. The receiver must accept cross origin calls. If that question wasn't helpful, here's a bunch more: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+No+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27+header+is+present+on+the+requested+resource